# Firebird .net provider is not listed

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, firebird, firebird2.5

I have followed Jiří Činčura's post about Entity Framework 6 with Firebird @ http://blog.cincura.net/233426-entity-framework-6-with-firebird/ and did exactly what is written but Firebird provider is not listed when I try to add new connection (dbfirst). Later, I have read about DDEX and installed, configured machine.config but still nothing.
I am using VS2013 + EF 6 + .NET 4.5
[image]

What should I do additionally?

TIA.

Comment: You showed only values for Sql Server. The important thing is what's listed in the Data Provider listbox. If the provider you are after is not on this listbox it would indicate that it did not install correctly. One way of checking what DDEX providers are installed is to look at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\DataProviders

Comment: I have check the registry and there is no entries for VS 2013 as I expected, so create related entries copied from VS 2012 config. I got FireBird provider listed but now there is another problem, it cannot retrieve table names. So I gave up, as new DDEX is out, I give it a try. Uninstalled DDEX 3.0, deleted modified entries from registry, and installed DDEX 3.0.1. Yes it shows FireBird provider as I got with registry hack, but same problem resides; Cannot retrieve tables...

Comment: According to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525490/firebird-ddex-3-0-1-with-vs2013-system-data-entity-core-mappingexception) it is a know bug.

Comment: Have You Tried the Code first Existing Database approach ,you wont need DDEX To Do it that way

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same situation with Visual Studio 2013 and Firebird DDEX Provider 3.0.2.0.

In my case, the problem was the MSI file.

VS2013 is the only version I have in my computer. For some reason, the installer in its default settings, configures the system for VS2015, which has never been on my computer.

I just needed to uninstall, run the msi again and click on the "Advanced" button. First it will ask for the folder and next, for your VS and operating system version.

I had VS2015 selected, so I uncheked and selected the correct settings, VS2013, 64bit OS.