# Firebird DDEX 3.0.1 with VS2013 System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException

Tags: visual-studio-2013, firebird, entity-framework-6

I am using VS2013 + EF 6 + .NET 4.5, installed FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient via nuget like;

```
install-package FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient-EF6
```

After, I installed DDEX 3.0.1, try to add new Entity Data Model (DB First), define new connection with successful "Test Connection". And then, when it tries to retrieve database objects, it gives me below exception;

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

TIA.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known issue](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-542) when using EDMX (Code First is not affected).

Comment: Is closed, but I have the same problem with latest libraries (4.1.0.0/3.0.1.0).